# Does applying resources improve time?

Tags: hash, brute-force-attack

A password hash function is applied 12 times to secure a password. If it takes 21 minutes to brute force one application of the hash with the available resources, how long will it take to brute force the password if the available resources are quadrupled.

I believe it takes the same amount of time. Is this accurate?

Comment: This really depends on a number of things: Does one evaluation of the hash take 21 minutes or does the 12-fold application take 21 minutes or does a brute-force search of a singly-hashed password take 21 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if the quadrupling the available resources cuts down on the time it takes to brute force a password, it depends specifically on what resources you are talking about and how exactly they are 'quadrupled'. Are they made to run faster or are there simply four times as many? Simpling doubling the speed of a resource does not halve the time it takes for a process to complete. That depends on the percentage of the process that uses that resource. See this description of [Amdahl's law](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~byoung/cs429/slides23-amdahl.pdf) for a deeper look.

However, if you are asking for the amount of time it would take to brute force a password which a system hashes 12 times (given that we have the final hash), that is easy to calculate. Let the final hash = $C_{12}$. Supposing it takes 21 minutes to find a string $M_{11}$ such that H($M_{11}$) = $C_{12}$, then it takes 21 minutes to work backward to the second-to-last hash, $C_{11}$. Now we have $M_{11}$ = $C_{11}$. To find $M_{10}$ such that H($M_{10}$) = $C_{11}$, that would take us another 21 minutes to brute force. You continue backwards, each time taking 21 minutes to brute force the previous hash until you get the original $M_{1}$ such that H($M_{1}$) = $C_{1}$. This is your password, given that the system has no other built-in safeguards, such as padding extra plaintext onto the user's password before hashing it. Therefore, it would take 21 * 12 = 252 minutes to brute force the password.

Comment: Brute force cracking is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). If all available resources go up by a factor of k then the crack rate will also go up by a factor of k. You can get a linear speedup by parallelization as long different cores don't guess the same password. You need almost no communication between cores and the overhead behind the logic of preventing redundant guesses will be insignificant compared to slow password processing functions.

Comment: As long as you're not overlooking resources less obvious than processor clock speed and the number of processors. Eg. power budgets, cooling, and, in the case of memory hard functions, RAM bandwidth.

Comment: And that's if you do performance analysis in the abstract. For real machines and cracking operations where people can choose the hardware they want to use, you might want to consider that crackers will see an economy of scale effect. ("Cheaper in bulk" or "better than linear" basically.) A person could decide to buy less powerful machines with a slower clockrate but still come out ahead because such machines could be smaller, cheaper, and more energy efficient. In some extreme case, maybe even the upfront investment for ASIC-based cracking is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

What resources do you have available?

Suppose you have one computer that can cover the space of passwords in 21 minutes.

If the only additional resources you can provide are more time to run that one computer, then obviously you can't make it take less time.

But if you can buy six additional computers and teach them to explore nonoverlapping subsets of the password space, you can break it in 3 minutes, assuming it takes less than 3 minutes to evaluate the hash once, which it almost certainly does.  Of course, it doesn't *cost* less because now you're drawing seven times the power, so it'll use the same amount of energy and—barring variations in local utility pricing—cost the same, even if it takes less time.

If you want to break *one of $k$ unsalted passwords*, you can do even better.  Suppose the password space has $n$ elements (*e.g.*, $2^{128}$).  At the cost of only about $np/k$ evaluations of the password hash, you can use [Oechslin's rainbow tables](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-45146-4_36), which save effort between the effort to break many passwords at once, to get the first of $k$ passwords with probability $p$, although it costs enough additional memory and communication that it's not *cheaper* overall to carry out.  However, by [parallelizing the rainbow table machine at least $k^2$ ways](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#bruteforce), you can get an answer in the *time* for about $np/k^3$ sequential evaluations of the password hash and in *area*time* cost (which is a good proxy for rubles, or for kilowatt hours) of $np/k$ for the whole computation.